# Install battery on honda generator?

Tags: electrical, generator, battery

I have a Honda generator and I want to install the battery. Somebody else took the old battery out, so I don’t how they did that.

The problem is that I only see a gray cable, a black cable, and a weird cable on the other side. I don’t see a red cable.

How do I install the battery?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trace the cables. The one connected to the chassis is negative

And the other one goes to the positive.

Comment: There are only two cables that connect to the battery.

Comment: If I connect the black cable to the black terminal, the only cable left is the gray cable. There isn’t “the other two cables”.

Comment: The gray one goes to the positive terminal?

Comment: @rbhat So have you followed the cables? If not and you don’t, then don’t connect anything - pay a professional.

Comment: I’ll trace the cables, but the picture shows what I see.

Comment: @rbhat why would you connect the black cable to the black terminal?  What basis would you have for that choice?  *since they are clearly not color-coded like that*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica : if you think I’m doing it wrong, then post an answer explaining how the battery should be installed.

Comment: Why criticize me using an someone else’s answer? Post an answer explaining how it should be done. That’s the purpose of SE.

Comment: @rbhat No thanks, you're too argumentative and not that interested in actually working the problem.

Comment: Suggestion for the OP: the person that donated their time to provide you a perfectly useful answer was initially unclear, but edited the answer. Now it's on you to delete your comments that address the un-edited answer. By the way, if you have a multimeter, there's zero resistance between any chassis bolt and the negative cable.

Comment: My apologies to Solar Mike. I read the first answer he provided.